Delete token fron dev-chain
In order to get familiar with the spl-token cli, I did some tests and created three token on the dev chain. Now I am wondering if there is a way to remove/delete them in order to clean up.

It's impossible to close SPL Token mints unless you created them with spl-token-2022 and added the --enable-close flag when calling create-token.
